# how to select the elements using xpath locator

Tags: html, xpath

My HTML

```
<table id="mainTable" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="center" colspan="14">State Wise Revenue of a Bank (all Figures are in INR and in Lacs)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>State \ Month</td>
<td>
<a href="#" onclick="">November</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#" onclick="">December</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#" onclick="">January</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#" onclick="">February</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#" onclick="">March</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#" onclick="">April</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#" onclick="">May</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#" onclick="">June</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#" onclick="">July</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#" onclick="">August</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#" onclick="">September</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#" onclick="">October</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#" onclick="">Operation</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Sikkim</td>
<td>
<div id="1_1" name="1">71481</div>
</td>
<td>
<div id="1_2" name="1">10413</div>
</td>
<td>
<div id="1_3" name="1">75560</div>
</td>
<td>
<div id="1_4" name="1">32333</div>
</td>
<td>
<div id="1_5" name="1">21008</div>
</td>
<td>
<div id="1_6" name="1">70787</div>
</td>
<td> 
<div id="1_7" name="1">6758</div>
</td>
<td>
<div id="1_8" name="1">47243</div>
</td>
<td>
<div id="1_9" name="1">65985</div>
</td>
<td>
<div id="1_10" name="1">80545</div>
</td>
<td>
<div id="1_11" name="1">54327</div>
</td>
<td>
<div id="1_12" name="1">72603</div>
</td>
<td>
<a id="Edit_1" href="#" onclick="fnEditRevenue("1");">Edit</a>
|
<a id="Hide_1" href="#" onclick="fnHideRevenue(1);">Hide</a>
|
<a id="Show_1" href="#" style="visibility:hidden" onclick="fnShowRevenue(1);">Show</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>Tripura</td>
<td>
<div>
<input id="3_1" type="text" value="4851" style="width:50px" name="U3">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("3_1")" style="width:60px">
</div>
```

I want to select 'tripura' and its sibling text box in firepath using xpath but by using following xpath I am able to select 'tripura','textbox','update button'

```
//td[.='Tripura']/following-sibling::*/*
```

so my question is how to avoid selecting 'update button'.Any help?

Comment: Could you post the *exact HTML* of selected elements when using current xpath?

Comment: check my answer. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following xpath successfully select the *textbox* for me, if that what you wanted :

```
//td[.='Tripura']/following-sibling::td/div/input[@type='text']
```

**selected element :** (using firepath)

```
<input id="3_1" type="text" name="U3" style="width:50px" value="4851"/>
```